# debugging multi process java applications

Tags: java, debugging

What is a good system for debugging a multi process Java application where it isn't clear which process should be debugged?

For example, in Python I can use [rpdb](https://pypi.org/project/rpdb/) and add the line `import rpdb; rpdb.set_trace()` so execution blocks until I connect to the debugger with e.g. `nc 127.0.0.1 4444`.

Compared to the above quick and reliable method, when I'm using a Java debugger, I see the following challenges:

1. Ensure that every process is run with proper arguments to allow debugging -- in my case it isn't clear what is starting all the processes so it isn't obvious where to change the arguments.  Is there a way to change the defaults on my computer to always include the jvm options `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044`?
2. Decide what process to connect the debugger to before the desired code is hit -- again, it isn't clear which process I should connect to, and it is convenient that `rpdb` blocks until the debugger connects and you don't need to identify the process id.  Is there anything similar to this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Start java with something like:

```
java -agentlib:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=1044
```

The `suspend=y` bit tells the VM to wait until a debugger connects before running main(). `address` is the port to connect to.

Comment: What if there are a dozen processes involved and you don't know what process to connect to?  What if it is random which process handles a request?  Seems like it would be very time consuming to connect a dozen debuggers.